# Compute overlapping time intervals across dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

I am trying to compute which rows overlaps in time with any other row on a `DataFrame`. Given this example:

```
            df = spark.createDataFrame(
            [
                [1,"2020:01:01 12:00", "2020:01:01 13:00"], # T
                [1,"2020:01:01 12:30", "2020:01:01 13:00"], # T
                [1,"2020:01:01 14:00", "2020:01:01 15:00"], # F
                [2,"2020:01:01 09:00", "2020:01:01 13:00"], # F
                [2,"2020:01:01 18:00", "2020:01:01 19:00"], # F
            ],
            ["id", "start", "end"]
        )
        w = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("start").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)
        df.withColumn("OVERLAPS", ?????.over(w)).show()
```

I would like to generate a column that signal whenever two rows with the same `id` overlaps in time:

```
                [1,"2020:01:01 12:00", "2020:01:01 13:00", True], 
                [1,"2020:01:01 12:30", "2020:01:01 13:00", True], 
                [1,"2020:01:01 14:00", "2020:01:01 15:00", False], 
                [2,"2020:01:01 09:00", "2020:01:01 13:00", False], 
                [2,"2020:01:01 18:00", "2020:01:01 19:00", False],
```

Ideally I could create time intervals, in pandas it would be using `pd.IntervalIndex` and I would have intervals which I could query, for example `"2020:01:01 13:00" in [2020:01:01 12:30, 2020:01:01 14:00)`

But I've been struggling to do it on spark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I gave this a go, in scala, though, and my solution is ugly and could probably improved upon (the whole column renaming and such especially). I made one assumption, which is that the times are already parsed into some integer format, then I basically solved this with a little more complicated join:

```
val s = Seq(
    (1, 1200, 1300),
    (1, 1230, 1300),
    (1, 1400, 1500),
    (2, 900, 1300),
    (2, 1800, 1900)
)

val df = s.toDF("id", "start", "end").withColumn("i", monotonicallyIncreasingId)
val dfr = df.select($"id", $"start".alias("start_r"), $"end".alias("end_r"), $"i".alias("i_r")) 

val overlaps = df.join(
    dfr,
    df("id") === dfr("id") 
        and df("start") <= dfr("end_r") 
        and df("end") >= dfr("start_r") 
        and (df("i") !== dfr("i_r"))
    ).select($"i".alias("i_overlaps"), lit(true).alias("overlaps"))

val result = df.join(overlaps, df("i") === overlaps("i_overlaps"), "left").
        drop("i_overlaps").
        withColumn("overlaps", when($"overlaps".isNull, false).otherwise($"overlaps"))

result.show
```

result:

```
+---+-----+----+---+--------+                                                   
| id|start| end|  i|overlaps|
+---+-----+----+---+--------+
|  1| 1200|1300|  0|    true|
|  1| 1230|1300|  1|    true|
|  2|  900|1300|  3|   false|
|  1| 1400|1500|  2|   false|
|  2| 1800|1900|  4|   false|
+---+-----+----+---+--------+
```

You can ofc drop the `i` column again. In this solution it is also not needed to repartition or sort the dataframe at all as this will be handled within the join. Probably, this type of join is not the most efficient, though :)